# Custom code needed to be executed on login and logout

Tags: login

Hello I am developing a website with WordPress. I need to set an extra cookie when users login to my site and delete that cookie when users logout from my site. Can anyone tell me, in which WordPress php file I have to put the codes. Thanks

Comment: add some more details about the code you are going to use to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

Never modify WordPress core files directly. You should read up on WP architecture, which is event based. You want to find a correct action and hook into it.

You need [wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) and [wp_logout](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_logout) action hooks.

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    // create cookie
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function');


function your_function() {
    // delete cookie
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'your_function');
?>
```

These can go in `functions.php`, or be encapsulated as a plugin.